# Ungrouping the grouped table in Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have the following data:

```
53,Male,11th,<=50K 
53,Male,11th,<=50K  
53,Male,11th,<=50K
20,Female,Masters,>50K 
20,Female,Masters,>50K
33,Male,Bachelors,<=50K
```

Next I need to group the above data by using select and group. so it will be something like:

```
53,Male,11th,<=50K,3 
20,Female,Masters,>50K,2 
33,Male,Bachelors,<=50K,1
```

where the last number shows the number of similar records. Now I need to filter the number of equivalent records > 2, and store it in a separate file

I have grouped data by sql queries in Scala command. To ungroup data, I though we may create a table and add the grouped data by (insert command), and line by line. It works, but this is very very slow, and took around one hour for few records. Is there any thoughts using Scala with many thanks.
The command is shown below:

```
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
import scala.collection.immutable.Map
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}


case class Rating(age: Double,edu: String, sex: String, salary: String)

val Result = sc.textFile("hdfs://NameNode01:9000/input/adult.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Rating(p(0).trim.toDouble,p(1),p(2),p(3))).toDF()
Result.registerTempTable("Start")

val sal1=spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT  age,edu,sex,salary,count(*) as cnt from Start group by age,edu,sex,salary")
sal1.registerTempTable("adult")

val sal2=spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT  age,edu,sex,salary,cnt from adult WHERE cnt>3")
sal2.registerTempTable("adult2")

var ag=sal2.map(age => ""+age(0)).collect()
var ed=sal2.map(edu => ""+edu(1)).collect()
var se=sal2.map(sex => ""+sex(2)).collect()
var sa=sal2.map(salary => ""+salary(3)).collect()
var cn=sal2.map(cnt => ""+cnt(4)).collect()

//convert age to double
val ages= ag.map(_.toDouble)

//convert the cnt to integer
val counts= cn.map(_.toInt)

//length of the array
var cnt_length=counts.size


//create a table and add the sal2 records in it
val adlt2=spark.sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE adult3 (age double, edu string, sex string, salary string)")


//loop and enter the number of cn
var sql_querys="query"
var i=0
var j=0
var loop_cnt=0

for(i <-0 to cnt_length-1){
   loop_cnt=counts(i)
    for(j <-0 to loop_cnt-1){
        sql_querys="INSERT into adult3 values ("+ages(i)+",'"+ed(i)+"','"+se(i)+"','"+sa(i)+"')"

        val adlt3=spark.sqlContext.sql("INSERT into adult3 values ("+ages(i)+",'"+ed(i)+"','"+se(i)+"','"+sa(i)+"')")
    }

}
```

The main part is the loop at the end of the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you really ask for.. could you please give data examples of `sal1`, `sal2` and the desired output?

Comment: you can edit that into your post.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter solution which uses only rdds:

```
val result = sc
  .textFile("hdfs://NameNode01:9000/input/adult.csv")
  .map({ (line: String) =>
    val p = line.split(",")
    (Rating(p(0).trim.toDouble,p(1),p(2),p(3)), 1)
  })
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .filter(_._2 > 2)
  .flatMap(rating => Array.fill(rating._2)(rating._1))
```

It works as follows:

- `textfile` loads the rdd from the file
- `map` transforms the lines to pairs of the form `(rating, 1)`
- `reduceByKey` groups the pairs by the `rating` and sums the 1s (i.e. counts the occurrences of each rating)
- `filter` discards the ratings which appear less than 3 times
- `flatmap` repeats each rating so many times as its count and then flattens all the results to a single rdd

Here are some reasons why the initial approach is not performant:

1. `collect` is used on the dataframe to read its contents on a local machine. This means that you directly loose all parallelization and clustering benefits of spark.
2. The `for` loop executes single insertions to the dataframe. The available transformations of spark objects (e.g. `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, single sql queries) are highly optimised to perform those actions in a distributed fashion. By using a for loop to perform single row actions, you loose this advantage and additionally you risk getting extreme overhead by dataframes which are copied during each iteration in the loop.
3. (minor) Converting an RDD to a dataframe adds some additional computational cost. Thus unless you plan to perform several operations which would benefit from performance features of dataframes or datasets, I would suggest keeping it simple by using just rdds.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider ungrouping your dataframe using `explode` in accordance with the `groupBy` count:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Rating(age: Double, edu: String, sex: String, salary: String)

val Result = sc.textFile("/Users/leo/projects/spark/files/testfile.csv").
  map(_.split(",")).
  map(p => Rating(p(0).trim.toDouble, p(1).trim, p(2).trim, p(3).trim)).
  toDF

val saDF1 = Result.groupBy("age", "edu", "sex", "salary").agg(count("*") as "cnt")

val saDF2 = Result.groupBy("age", "edu", "sex", "salary").agg(count("*") as "cnt").where($"cnt" > 2)

// Create a UDF to fill array of 1's to be later exploded
val fillArr = (n: Int) => Array.fill(n)(1)
val fillArrUDF = udf(fillArr)

val expandedDF1 = saDF1.withColumn("arr", fillArrUDF($"cnt"))

expandedDF1.show
+----+------+---------+------+---+---------+
| age|   edu|      sex|salary|cnt|      arr|
+----+------+---------+------+---+---------+
|33.0|  Male|Bachelors| <=50K|  1|      [1]|
|20.0|Female|  Masters|  >50K|  2|   [1, 1]|
|53.0|  Male|     11th| <=50K|  3|[1, 1, 1]|
+----+------+---------+------+---+---------+

// Ungroup dataframe using explode
val ungroupedDF1 = expandedDF1.withColumn("a", explode($"arr")).
  select("age", "edu", "sex", "salary")

ungroupedDF1.show
+----+------+---------+------+
| age|   edu|      sex|salary|
+----+------+---------+------+
|33.0|  Male|Bachelors| <=50K|
|20.0|Female|  Masters|  >50K|
|20.0|Female|  Masters|  >50K|
|53.0|  Male|     11th| <=50K|
|53.0|  Male|     11th| <=50K|
|53.0|  Male|     11th| <=50K|
+----+------+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

According to what I understood from your question that you want to filter out similar records which are greater than 2 and write to a file. If thats so following can be your solution.

You must already have original dataframe as

```
+----+------+---------+------+
|age |edu   |sex      |salary|
+----+------+---------+------+
|53.0|Male  |11th     |<=50K |
|53.0|Male  |11th     |<=50K |
|53.0|Male  |11th     |<=50K |
|20.0|Female|Masters  |>50K  |
|20.0|Female|Masters  |>50K  |
|33.0|Male  |Bachelors|<=50K |
+----+------+---------+------+
```

You don't need to write complex sql queries to find the count, you can just use inbuilt functions as

```
val columnNames = Result.columns
val finalTemp = Result.groupBy(columnNames.map(col): _*).agg(count("salary").as("similar records"))
```

This should give output as

```
+----+------+---------+------+---------------+
|age |edu   |sex      |salary|similar records|
+----+------+---------+------+---------------+
|33.0|Male  |Bachelors|<=50K |1              |
|20.0|Female|Masters  |>50K  |2              |
|53.0|Male  |11th     |<=50K |3              |
+----+------+---------+------+---------------+
```

Now to filter, you can just use filter function as

```
val finalTable = finalTemp.filter($"similar records" < 3)
```

final output is

```
+----+------+---------+------+---------------+
|age |edu   |sex      |salary|similar records|
+----+------+---------+------+---------------+
|33.0|Male  |Bachelors|<=50K |1              |
|20.0|Female|Masters  |>50K  |2              |
+----+------+---------+------+---------------+
```

you can save it to a file

```
finalTable.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("output path")
```

If you want the original data with filtered out then you can simply use join as

```
Result.join(finalTable, Seq(columnNames: _*)).show(false)
```

output is

```
+----+------+---------+------+---------------+
|age |edu   |sex      |salary|similar records|
+----+------+---------+------+---------------+
|33.0|Male  |Bachelors|<=50K |1              |
|20.0|Female|Masters  |>50K  |2              |
|20.0|Female|Masters  |>50K  |2              |
+----+------+---------+------+---------------+
```

You can save it to a file as above

Note: you will need following import for above functions to work

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```